# Separate multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a multi dimensional array in PHP.

```
$f = array('one' => array(*doesntmatter*), two => array());
```

When I want to use it, I only want one of the arrays. (one or two or three etc)
So I want to slice it into (in this case) two seperate arrays, like this:

```
$one = array(**); $two = array(**);
```

Can I solve this with a default function, or I have to write it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [extract()](http://us.php.net/extract) to do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

to explicitly call each member:

```
$foo = array('one' => array(1,2,3), 'two' => array(4,5,6));
$one = $foo['one'];
$two = $foo['two'];
```

or you can use [extract()](http://us.php.net/extract)

```
extract($foo);
print_r($one);print_r($two);
```

Answer (score 0):

$one = $f['one']